# CRUD issue while edit and save from table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i tried to click the edit radio button the details will be displayed in the concerned boxes but the existing details in the table is deleted. Here my requirement is to use single array/scope variable for edit, display and delete. But no use for loop while edit/delete. Here i done the changes but no proper way of work. my html index.html as follows

```
<div ng-controller="employeeController">
    <header><h1>Employee Details</h1></header>

    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
        <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
            <tr>
                <td><label> Employee Id </Label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="eid" data-ng-model="employees.EmployeeId" data-ng-required="true" ng-disabled="newEmployees"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label> FirstName </Label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname" data-ng-model="employees.FirstName" data-ng-required="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label> LastName </Label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname" data-ng-model="employees.LastName" data-ng-required="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label> Gender </Label></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-ng-change="employees.Gender" value ="Male" data-ng-model="employees.Gender"/> Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" data-ng-change="employees.Gender" value ="Female" data-ng-model="employees.Gender"/>Female
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label> Email </Label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" data-ng-model="employees.Email" data-ng-required="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label> Account </Label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="account" data-ng-model="employees.Account" data-ng-required="true"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" data-ng-model="employees.EmployeeId"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button name="btnSave" data-ng-click="saveEmployeeRecord(employees)" class="userbutton">Save</button>
        <button name="btnReset" data-ng-click="resetEmployeeRecord()" class="userbutton">Reset</button>
    </form> 

    <table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tr style="color: blue">
            <th style="width:100px">Employee Id</th>
            <th style="width:150px">FirstName</th>
            <th style="width:150px">LastName</th>
            <th style="width:90px">Gender</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Email</th>
            <th style="width:60px">Account</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
       <tr style="color:green" data-ng-repeat="emp in employees">
           <td>{{emp.EmployeeId}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.FirstName}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.LastName}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.Gender}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.Email}}</td>
           <td>{{emp.Account}}</td>
           <td>
               <input type="radio" name="process" data-ng-click="editEmployee(emp, employees.indexOf(emp))"> Edit
               <input type="radio" name="process" data-ng-click="DeleteEmployee(employees.indexOf(emp))"> Delete
           </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

javascript app.js

```
var employeeApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

employeeApp.controller("employeeController", function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

            $http.get('data/employees.json').success(function(data) {

                $rootScope.employees = data;
            }); 

            var empId = 12342;
            $rootScope.saveEmployeeRecord = function(emp) {
                if($rootScope.employees.EmployeeId == null) {
                    $rootScope.employees.EmployeeId = empId++;
                    $rootScope.employees.push(emp);
                }
                else {
                    for(i in $rootScope.employees) {
                        if($rootScope.employees[i].EmployeeId == emp.EmployeeId) { 
                            $rootScope.employees[i]= emp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //$rootScope.employees = {};
            }

            $rootScope.resetEmployeeRecord = function() {
                angular.copy({}, $rootScope.employees);
            }

            $rootScope.editEmployee = function(emp, indx) {

                    //$rootScope.emp = $rootScope.employees;
                    if($rootScope.employees[indx].EmployeeId == emp.EmployeeId) { 
                        $rootScope.employees = angular.copy($rootScope.employees[indx]);
                    }


            }

            $rootScope.DeleteEmployee = function(idx) {

                var result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
                if (result) {
                    $rootScope.employees.splice(idx,1);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                     return false;
                }

                //for(i in $rootScope.employees) {
                    //if($rootScope.employees[i].EmployeeId == idx) { 

                        //$rootScope.employees = {};
                    //}
                //}
            }

});
```

employees.json file:

```
[
            {
                "EmployeeId": "61234",
                "LastName": "Anderson",
                "FirstName": "James",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "james_anderson@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "512458",
                "LastName": "Cambell",
                "FirstName": "Mike",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "mike.cambell@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "712785",
                "LastName": "Swachengar",
                "FirstName": "Andrew",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "andrew.swachengar@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Cisco"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "712734",
                "LastName": "Anderson",
                "FirstName": "James",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "james.anderson@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Apple"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "61245",
                "LastName": "Green",
                "FirstName": "Rachael",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Email": "rachael_green@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "61347",
                "LastName": "Brown",
                "FirstName": "Jackualine",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Email": "jackualine_brown@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            }
]
```

Comment: @Chun please help me

Comment: @Week Dev please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the selected item to a model which you have to associate in your edit/save form. And then when "save" is clicked, you need to update the original data with the updated data. Here's an example of how that would work:

```
        $rootScope.saveEmployeeRecord = function() {
            for(k in $scope.selectedEmployee){
             $scope.selectedEmployee[k] = $scope.selectedEmployeeCopy[k];
            }
        }

        $rootScope.resetEmployeeRecord = function() {
            $rootScope.selectedEmployeeCopy = null;
        }


        $rootScope.editEmployee = function(emp) {
            $rootScope.selectedEmployee = emp;
            $rootScope.selectedEmployeeCopy = angular.copy($rootScope.selectedEmployee);
        }
```

Here, I am making a copy of your original employee, and updating the copy. When saved, the copy will replace the original employee. When cancelled, it will be simply ignored. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qp5r7oh/2/) based on your code.

**Edit:** based on feedback, updated the save and delete method which were not working as expected. Also updated the jsFiddle.
**Edit2:** Removed for loops and relpaced with passing array index

```
    $rootScope.saveEmployeeRecord = function() {
            $rootScope.employees.splice($rootScope.selectedIndex, 1,$rootScope.selectedEmployeeCopy);
        }

        $rootScope.resetEmployeeRecord = function() {
            $rootScope.selectedEmployeeCopy = null;
            $rootScope.selectedIndex = null;
        }

        $rootScope.editEmployee = function(emp, ind) {
            $rootScope.selectedIndex = ind;
            $rootScope.selectedEmployee = emp;
            $rootScope.selectedEmployeeCopy = angular.copy($rootScope.selectedEmployee);
        }

        $rootScope.DeleteEmployee = function(emp, ind) {

            var result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
            if (result) {                    
                $rootScope.employees.splice(ind, 1);
                $rootScope.selectedEmployeeCopy = null;
                $rootScope.selectedIndex = null;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                 return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but when edit the existing thing the edited data have override the existing and add it in first row. please correct it and reply back.

Comment: My bad. Didn't realize until you pointed it out. I have updated the answer and the jsFiddle to fix the problems.

Comment: I already told the condtion is not use the for loop. instead any other option for save edit and delete. pls

Comment: Sure, check out my changes in the fiddle. You need to pass the index of the array in the function and you can get rid of the loops like I have it in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can Pass id as like this with your index in your radio button.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editBook(add.id, $index);" type="submit">Edit</button>
```

See my controller:

```
$scope.editBook = function(id,index) {
   $scope.show1=false;
   $scope.show=true;
   $http.get(appurl + 'user/adds/' + id + '.json')

        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.user= data; 

        angular.copy($scope.user, $scope.copy);
    });

};
```